# RBAC - how to model database to only have a single admin?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rbac

I am trying to plan out a RBAC app - I want to build a restaurant management app and it needs these following roles:

- a single master `Admin`
- `Managers`
- `Staffs`

The part where I am stuck is just how to be able to create a single user with the `Admin` role? I want to mimic a software where it goes through the signup process and have the single admin role user created.

I plan on using a NoSQL database and I'm only stuck in the data modelling part.

Comment: MongoDB has built-in roles (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/)  for superuser/admin and user defined roles(https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-user-defined-roles/) for custom roles such as managers and/or staff.  Users are created with roles, or roles can be granted later.  User granting roles must have authorization to grant roles.

Comment: when MongoDB is first installed no users exist.  Assuming authorization is turned off the user logging in has full admin rights.  Turn on authorization (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authorization/#enable-access-control) and use the "localhost exception" to create a user with a specific admin role.

Comment: Users & roles in MongoDB are generally not 1:1 with end users of an application. Application users should typically be accessing data via an API/application rather than direct database access. Can you edit your question to include an example of what your current data model looks like and what aspects of this model aren't working for you?